# Laravel scoreboard of more than 1 million users

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, apache, laravel-5

I'm working in a biggest application ( more than 1 million users ) and I try to get the ranking of each user in the scoreboard section but had this problem: **the result is very very slow**

This is the architecture of my database:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            ...
});
```

---

```
Schema::create('topics', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            ...
});
```

The topics table have than 20 row

---

```
    Schema::create('user_scores', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('topic_id')->unsigned();

        $table->unique(['user_id', 'topic_id']);

        $table->float('timer');
        $table->integer('score');
     });
```

**The query to make rank for users**

```
        User::where('type',0)->get()->each(function ($user) {
            $user->topics= $user->scores->sum('score');
            $user->timing= $user->scores->sum('timer');
        })->sort(function ($a, $b){
          return  ($b->topics - $a->topics) == 0  
            ? ($a->timing - $b->timing) 
            : ($b->topics - $a->topics);
        })->values()->each(function($user, $key){
                $user->rank = $key +1;
        });
```

Any optimization should I make the get the result quicker? Thanks.

Comment: You can't just expect everyone to guess what queries you are executing. Please give some examples, otherwise any suggestion will just be a better guess...

Comment: You sort them in PHP arrays, that's why the speed... Try to sort the rows in the database

Comment: @Alex an example please

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you call `get()`, `all()`, `find()` or `first()` on a query builder, you'll ask the Eloquent engine to perform the query and return you the result. So in your case, all the sorting and grouping is performed in memory, which comes with incredibly bad performance.

What you can do is to improve your query:

```
User::query()
    ->where('type', 0)
    ->withCount('scores as topics')
    ->withCount(['scores as timing' => function ($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('SUM(timer)'); // might look weird, but works...
    }])
    ->orderBy('topics', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('timing', 'desc')
    ->get()
```

For the row number (or rank, or however you wanna call it), you might want to search through existing questions and answers. Answering that as well would be too much for this answer, to be honest. Clearly you should not use your approach though, as it will also calculate the row number in memory.

But obviously it is also important what you are doing with the query results. Are you displaying one million rows to the user? If so, the bottleneck will be the browser in the end for sure. You might want to consider using pagination with `paginate()` instead of `get()`.

Comment: The 'withCount' return only the count of row (always 1). I don't display all result I get only top 3, and before and after the connected user   ( user-1, user, user+1)

Comment: `withCount('scores')` will return the number of associated rows in the `score` table. You can print the query with `toSql()` instead of `get()` to have a look yourself.

Comment: I need to order by the value of sum, not by the number of rows

Comment: Then just switch the `orderBy()` statements around.